# Unity game trouble

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity where I have to have a player (a ball) and three enemies (in this case three rotating cylinders). Whenever the player hits an enemy, I need it to die (which I have already done) and then print out Game over, which I don't know how to do. I also need the player to respawn after it dies, which is another think I don't know how to do. I also need to create three "virtual holes" where when the player rolls over them, it respawns, but not dies. I figure I can simulate holes by creating flat cylinders, but I don't know how to make the ball respawn but rolling over them.  Thank you in advance!! Please be clear about which part does what in your answer.

```
//My player script
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
private Rigidbody rb;
public float threshold;
public Text gameOver;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
//rolls the player according to x and z values
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
}




//my script that makes the enemy rotate and kills the player but after the
 player dies it just disappears
public class Rotater : MonoBehaviour {
public Text gameOver;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime);

}

//kills player
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision Col)
{
if (Col.gameObject.name == "Player")
{
    Destroy(Col.gameObject);
    gameOver.text = "Game over!";
 }

}




//my script that respawns the play if it falls off the maze
public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{

// respawns player if it goes below a certain point (falls of edge)
public float threshold;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (transform.position.y < threshold)
        transform.position = new Vector3(-20, 2, -24);
}
}
```

Comment: See the Roll-A-Ball tutorial: [Displaying the Score and Text](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/displaying-score-and-text?playlist=17141)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UI to draw text over your game. You can learn about it [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

When you have the UI in place, you can just activate/deactivate the relevant parts with [SetActive(bool)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

To kill and respawn the player, I suggest you not to destroy it and re-instantiate it. Instead, you can simply deactivate it and reactivate it in the new position using `SetActive(bool)` again.

For the holes, you can create other objects with colliders and use `OnCollisionEnter` as you already did but to change player's position.